# How can i add the Image Filter plugin in Xamarin.Form?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

First of all I am new in Xamarin.Form. I am trying to get best from Google but some of functionality I am not able to get even searched a lot.

I am creating a Xamarin.Form app. In that app I want to provide a functionality of image filter. In that, the image captured by user or get from their internal memory should by filter.

I have tried to search on google to get some idea for it in Xamarin.Form but I still not get any link which can help me to get start.

First of all I don't know whether it is possible in Xamarin.Form or not. Can anybody suggest me a link or idea to achieve it?

I attached a Screenshot so you can easily understand the problem.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QN760.jpg)

Comment: Please add some code to show what you have tried on your own.

Comment: @IshitaSinha Well, I have searched a lot about it but didn't find a single link which can help me to get start with the functionality that I require. I have edited my question. Can you please suggest me so I can get start atleast?

Answer (score 1):

There are no out of the box APIs in Xamarin.Forms for Image filters.

Each platforms handles the images differently, you will need to implement these filters per platform bases.

You can find the instructions for iOS [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction_to_coreimage/#Filters) and [here](https://prashantvc.com/2013/09/09/image-effects-with-xamarin-android/) for Android, then you can use the [`DependencyServices`](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/) to access them in Forms app